# Не могу найти js код с генерированием переменной

Tags: javascript, http

На [данном](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/auth) сайте я пытаюсь понять как происходит запрос на авторизацию. Как видно в Google Tools - Network сервер отправляет POST запрос с следующими данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переменную помеченную зелёным я не знаю как генерирует сайт. С помощью Event Listener-а я отследил нажатие кнопки "Войти" и она вызывает [этот](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/polyfills.38a28283707eff0aaec7.js) js скрипт (помечен зелёным):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот скрипт очень длинный и я не понимаю как он работает. Если вы разбираетесь как он работает или, если вам не сложно перейти на сайт и самим глянуть как там работает генерирование этой переменной, буду очень благодарен.

**ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАНО:**

Параметр client_secret присутствует в файле main.043e8968e34328301443.js. Данный файл страница получает с помощью запроса на сервер, следовательно, нужно выяснить как и где генерируется ссылка на это файл

Comment: сайт написан на ангуляре, со сборщиком webpack, при сборке он и вставляет все что необходимо, а также генерирует имена файлам

Comment: то-есть, можно просто сделать запрос к странице и из html вычленить ссылку на js код и распарсить его, так?

Comment: Данное значение статично, скорей всего простой Public Key.

Comment: @KuzCode, да, примерно так